# Akka Actors: ask pattern vs Promise

Tags: scala, promise, akka-actor

Lately I've found myself wrapping actors in classes so that I get back a little of the typesafety I lose when dealing with `ActorRef`s.
The problem is, at the end, that not only I need to send a specific message, I also need to cast the response to the expected result.
So I thought that I could send messages to actors that contain `Promise` so that they could report the result eventually.

Is that a bad idea? It looks pretty neat to me... Is typesafe and works just as good. Why hasn't anyone come with the idea? Is there anything wrong with it that I haven't noticed?

**ask pattern based solution**

```
case class GetUser(id:Long)

(actorRef ! GetUser(1l)).mapTo[User]

class UserRepoActor extends Actor{
  def receive={
   case GetUser(id)=>
     sender() ! getUser(id)
  }

  ...
}
```

**Promise based solution**

```
case class GetUser(id: Long, resp: Promise[User])

val req = GetUser(1l,Promise())
actorRef ! req
req.resp.future // No casting!!

class UserRepoActor extends Actor{
  def receive={
   case GetUser(id,resp)=>
     response.success(getUser(id))
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by sending messages to Actor's that contain Promises? In any case, you have to pattern match on the incoming message. Can you post some code samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. Very close approach is used in [akka typed](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.8/typed.html#introduction) with the only difference: a single-use `ActorRef[T]` is being sent instead of `Promise[T]`

Answer (score 1):

`Promise`s won't work in distributed actor system.

At least, without additional efforts for that.

Comment: Why? Any references?

Comment: Basically, documentation. They are just not designed with "distributed" in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Ask pattern is definitely better.

1) Actors are supposed to share no state and interact with the outer world via messages. Fulfilling the promise is actually a mutating shared variable

2) Passing the stateful objects into actor's creator (e.g. promise) breaks actor's lifecycle in case of restarts

So promise-based approach works in simple cases. But if you use it just like that probably you don't need such complicated stuff like akka at all?

Comment: Not entirely true. The more complex a solution is, the more it can make use of typesafety. At the end the promise-base solutions is just there to add typesafety. I get by the other two proposed solutions that if I want to use distributed systems, promise-based solution will fail, and that Akka is actually striving to add some typesafety in a similar fashion.

Comment: By passing a stateful object to an actor you workaround inconvenience of akka API but violate akka ideology. From my point of view it is a bigger evil. Not only in case of distributed systems as I pointed.